# Auto-relacionamento com Eloquent no Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou construindo uma aplicação de controle de imigrantes e possuo uma tabela imigrants que tem 3 auto relacionamentos. Sua estrutura é a seguinte.

- id -> pk
- first_name -> varchar
- last_name -> varchar
- (...)
- father -> integer (fk)
- mother -> integer (fk)
- spouse -> integer (fk)

Porém não estou conseguindo determinar a relação correta com o eloquent (ainda estou aprendendo a utilizar o laravel).
Já testei com hasOne, belongsTo etc. e não consigo fazer associar corretamente.
Ao utilizar por exemplo a query:

`$imigrant->father()->save($father)`

É adicionado a id de $imigrant em $father. Ao contrário do que desejo.
E se utilizo `belongsTo()` com `associate()`, ex:

`$imigrant->father()->associate($father)`

Ele seta null na id de $imigrant e faz um merge de $father ficando tipo:

```
App\Imigrant {#680
 id: null,
 first_name: "FName",
 last_name: "LName",
 birth_place: null,
 birth_date: null,
 disembark_place: null,
 disembark_date: null,
 father: App\Imigrant {#676
   id: 1,
   first_name: "FName2",
   last_name: "LName2",
   birth_place: null,
   birth_date: null,
   disembark_place: null,
   disembark_date: null,
   father: null,
   mother: null,
   spouse: null,
   ship: null,
   created_at: "2016-12-26 14:59:17",
   updated_at: "2016-12-26 14:59:17",
 },
 mother: null,
 spouse: null,
 ship: null,
 created_at: "2016-12-26 15:12:16",
 updated_at: "2016-12-26 15:12:16",
```

E não atualiza a base de dados.

Sei que poderia fazer a associação manual, mas queria utilizar os recursos de eager query que associa os dados e puxa automatico as associações na pesquisa. Se alguem puder me dar uma luz de como poderia fazer a associação no Model pra isso funcionar. Senão vou ter que me contentar em fazer na unha mesmo. :D

Comment: pow cara, pelo que entendi o nome da coluna no banco está fora do padrão que o laravel espera, então você vai ter que especificar ela na relação, tenta assim: `return $this->belongsTo('ModelDestino', 'father');` [Fonte](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: @JuniorNunes Cara, quebrei a cabeça aqui e acho que consegui resolver o caso. Eu tinha determinado o campo correto, senão ele ia dar exception no save e tal pq n iria achar a coluna correta. Mas como estava testando com hasOne, não estava dando certo e a relação estava saindo invertida. Mudei pra belongsTo e ta funcionando agora, era só usar um belongsTo pra cada fk, agora posso continuar a desenvolver o resto e achar mais algo pra quebrar a cabeça kkk

Comment: @JuniorNunes na verdade nem sei pq funcionou, havia testado antes e n tinha pego, mas pode ter sido burrada minha de esquecer de restartar o tinker pra atualizar as referencias.

Comment: Já perdi bastante tempo por esquecer de restartar o tinker kkk, que bom que resolveu, coloca uma resposta e marca como resolvido pra ajudar o pessoal que tiver o mesmo problema!

Comment: Uma dica para você se ligar quando usar `belongsTo` ou `hasOne` é o seguinte: O `belongsTo`, é quando a chave de referência está no Model que você está mexendo, exemplo: estou no User e tenho um campo chamado group_id, então eu tenho um `belongsTo` para groups, o hasOne, sempre vai te dar a possibilidade de também ser hasMany, por esse motivo a chave deve estar na outra tabela, pois seguindo o exemplo anterior um usuário não poderia ter muitos grupos, sacou? Exemplo de `hasOne`: Tabela users `hasOne` para tabela logs (logs tem um user_id)

Comment: @IsraelMerljak para cada integrante pode ter um pai apenas `father` e um pai pode vários imigrantes?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim, um father, um mother e um spouse para cada imigrante. possibilita um father ter varios "filhos" e uma mother tbm. Ainda tenho q verificar o caso do spouse q tem q ser 1-1. mas isso acho q seria só eu relacionar ambas tabelas na associação. O problema da questão já resolvi, vou marcar como ok. Valeu pelas respostas de todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de quebrar bastante a cabeça resolvi. Além de eu ter esquecido de restartar o tinker (minhas alterações n estavam refletindo). A associação correta para o meu caso era `$this->belongsTo()` porque a FK é local (esta na mesma tabela).

Obrigado pelas respostas, ajudaram bastante :D

Aqui esta como ficou o Model funcionando (a princípio):

```
class Imigrant extends Model
{
    protected $genders = [
        "m" => "masculino",
        "f" => "feminino"
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "gender"
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        "created_at",
        "updated_at",
        "birth_date",
        "disembard_date"
    ];

    public function father()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Imigrant", "father_id");
    }

    public function mother()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Imigrant", "mother_id");
    }

    public function spouse()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Imigrant", "spouse_id");
    }

    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Document");
    }

    public function contributions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Contribution");
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Imigrant")->where("father_id", $this->id);
    }

    public function associateFather(Imigrant $father)
    {
        $r = $father->save();
        $this->father()->associate($father);
        return $this->save() == $r;
    }

    public function associateMother(Imigrant $mother)
    {
        $r = $mother->save();
        $this->mother()->associate($mother);
        return $this->save() == $r;
    }

    public function associateSpouse(Imigrant $spouse)
    {
        $spouse->spouse_id = $this->id;
        $r = $spouse->save();
        $this->spouse()->associate($spouse);
        return $this->save() == $r;
    }

    public function getGenderAttribute($value)
    {
        if ($this->gender == "Masculino") {
            return $this->hasMany("App\Imigrant", "father_id");
        } else {
            return $this->hasMany("App\Imigrant", "mother_id");
        }
    }
}
```